# How to get state from child to parent react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React

I have two components. Parent `Square`, child `Row`.

I want to get setValues `cellTop` and `cellLeft` from `Row` to parent and use it.

How can I do it.

My code is bellow

```js
var Square = React.createClass({


 getInitialState: function () {

  return {

  countRow: 4,
  countCol: 4,
  mouseOnTable: false,
  onDelRow: false,
  onDelCol: false

  }

 },


 appendCol: function() {

  var countColNew = this.state.countCol + 1;

  this.setState({countCol: countColNew});  //change initiale state "countCol" (add new column)

  //console.log(this.state.countCol)

 },

 appendRow: function() {

  var countRowNew = this.state.countRow + 1;

  this.setState({countRow: countRowNew});  //change initiale state "countRow" (add new row)

  //console.log(this.state.countRow)

 },

 deleteCol: function() {

  var countColNew = this.state.countCol - 1;

  this.setState({countCol: countColNew});  //change initiale state "countCol" (delete col)

  //console.log(this.state.countCol)

 },

 deleteRow: function() {

  var countRowNew = this.state.countRow - 1;

  this.setState({countRow: countRowNew});  //change initiale state (delete row)

  //console.log(this.state.countRow)

 },


 hiddenButtons: function(){
  var mouseOnTableNew = true;
  this.setState({mouseOnTable: mouseOnTableNew})
 },


 showButtons: function(){
  var mouseOnTableNew = false;
  this.setState({mouseOnTable: mouseOnTableNew})
 },



 render: function() {

  var timeOut;


  return (

   <div className='square'>

    <table className='square__table'
       onMouseOver={this.hiddenButtons}                
       onMouseLeave={() => {timeOut=setTimeout(this.showButtons,200)}}>


       <Row countRow={this.state.countRow}
         countCol={this.state.countCol}
         ref={(ref) => this.state}

         />  


    </table>


       <button className="square__button square__button_append square__button_col-append"
         onClick={this.appendCol}>
       </button>


             <button className="square__button square__button_delete square__button_col-delete" 
               style={this.state.countCol===1 ||
                   this.state.mouseOnTable===false ||
                   this.state.onDelRow===true ? {visibility: "hidden"} : {visibility: "visible"}}

               onClick={this.deleteCol}
               onMouseOver={() => {clearTimeout(timeOut);
                    this.setState({onDelCol:true})}}
               onMouseLeave={() => {this.setState({onDelCol:false})}}>
             </button>


             <button className="square__button square__button_append square__button_row-append" 
               onClick={this.appendRow}>
             </button>


             <button className="square__button square__button_delete square__button_row-delete"
               style={this.state.countRow===1 ||
                   this.state.mouseOnTable===false ||
                   this.state.onDelCol===true ? {visibility: "hidden"} : {visibility: "visible"}} 

               onClick={this.deleteRow}

               onMouseOver={() => {clearTimeout(timeOut);
                    this.setState({onDelRow:true})}}

               onMouseLeave={() => {this.setState({onDelRow:false})}}>
             </button>



    

   </div>


  )

 }

})


//==================================================


var Row = React.createClass({



 getInitialState: function(){
  return {

   cellTop: 0,
   cellLeft: 0,

  }


 },



 createCol: function() {

  var columns = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < this.props.countCol; i++){
   columns.push(this.createCell)
  }

  return columns;


 },



 createRow: function (k) {

  return (

   <tr key={k}>
    {this.createCol().map(function(cell,key){
     return (
       cell(key)
      )
    })}
   </tr>
  )
 },



 createCell: function(k){

  return (

   <td key={k}>
    <div className="square__cell" onMouseOver={this.getMousePosition}></div>
   </td>
  )

 },


 getMousePosition: function(element){

  let coordinates = element.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let top = coordinates.top;
  let left = coordinates.left;
  
  this.setState({
   cellTop: top,
   cellLeft: left
  })


 },



 render: function(){

   var lines = []
   for (let i = 0; i < this.props.countRow; i++) {
   lines.push(this.createRow(i))
  }


  return (

   <tbody>  
    {lines}
   </tbody>
  )
 }



})
```

Comment: Data flows in one direction only, you can pass data from parent to childs, not childs to parent

Comment: Can I declare this states in parent and change it from child dynamically?

Comment: No. You need to think it from another direction. Make your parent customize the rows, not the rows customize the parent. For example if you resize your parent based on your rows size, make rows resize on parent size.

Comment: You can indeed lift state up from a child component to a parent component. [Read more here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up). Also, you're using old React `createClass` for some reason. If you got this from a tutorial then I would advise against it, as it is pretty out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your child component a callback function that accepts two arguments, `cellTop` and `cellLeft`. In your child component pass `cellTop` and `cellLeft` values at the same time you are calling `getMousePosition()` function in your child component.

In your parent component create a function like this:

```
handleSizeChange: function(cellTop, cellLeft){
    this.setState({
        cellTop: cellTop,
        cellLeft: cellLeft
    })
},
```

In your Parent `<Row>` component pass a callback function as a prop like this:

```
<Row countRow={this.state.countRow}
     countCol={this.state.countCol}
     ref={(ref) => this.state}
     onSizeChange={this.handleSizeChange}
/>
```

In your Child component add `this.props.handleSizeChange(top, left)` to your `getMousePostion()` function:

```
getMousePosition: function(element){

    let coordinates = element.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let top = coordinates.top;
    let left = coordinates.left;

    this.setState({
        cellTop: top,
        cellLeft: left
    })

    this.props.handleSizeChange(top, left)
},
```

Its also true that whenever possible its best for data to flow from `Parent` -> `Child` components, but callback functions are common for things like button events.  You could use something like Redux to handle state management, but that is fairly advanced and is probably overkill if this is a simple beginner application.

Also, you should be using the newest React syntax for components.  Create new classes like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
          super()

          //getinitialstate
          this.state = {
            cellTop: 0,
            cellLeft: 0
          }
      }
}
```

and define class methods like this:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    // this runs right before the <App> is rendered

  })
```

Comment: Already did something like you wrote and it works now.
Also now will read more detailed how it works in your way!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to not use state in components at all. This just leads to problems when you want to control parent component from child.

Instead,

- make all components to receive data via props
- move state and all data into external object (store)
- make the store update your components when the data changes
- from components just update store

Look at https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs

```
+---------+       +--------+       +-----------------+
¦ Actions ¦------>¦ Stores ¦------>¦ View Components ¦
+---------+       +--------+       +-----------------+
     ^                                      ¦
     +--------------------------------------+
```